# Built-in App Launch keyboard shortcut in LinuxMint

Tags: linux-mint

Using LinuxMint 12, if you open the "desktops overview" by clicking on the top left corner of the desktop, a little search bar opens on the top-right corner of the desktop. This search does quick app launching without requiring additional plugins, but I can't get an answer on how to get to this launcher without using the mouse.

Does anyone know how I can invoke this launcher with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alt+F1** opens the Open Windows selection screen. If you start typing then, the search bar will automatically take focus.